# Determine filename at an LBA (NTFS)

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs, filenames, hard-drive-recovery

I ran Seagate's tools on my hard drive.  It reports that there are errors and gives the LBA numbers.  I would like to move the data at these locations to other locations on the drive.

How do I find out what files the data at those LBAs belong to?

*The disk is 1TB, using NTFS.

I'm running Windows 7, 64-bit platform.

The drive is connected internally via SATA interface.*

*Due to the size of the drive, I'm having problems finding resources to back it up; so I only want to move the files that are in danger (i.e. residing on the bad LBAs).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by LBA you mean the logical sectors:

1. Convert them to filesystem clusters (e.g. my system has 8 sectors per cluster):

   ```
   C:\>fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c:
   ...
   Bytes Per Sector  :               512
   Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
   ...

   C:\>set/a 13091568 / (4096 / 512)
   1636446
   ```
2. Use `fsutil volume querycluster`:

   ```
   C:\>fsutil volume querycluster c: 1636446
   Cluster 0x000000000018f85e used by ----D \Users\Mantas\example.txt::$DATA
   ```
3. Optionally, [verify](https://superuser.com/q/908218) using `fsutil file queryextents` or `fsutil volume filelayout`, both of which will show the complete start–end ranges of that file.

Comment: The LBA are the numbers reported by the Seagate SeaTools.  They report bad LBA numbers.  I want to know which files, if any, are located on these LBA.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have to substract offset of partition first